# Generic (web)app for creating custom forms and storing data

Tags: forms

I'm looking for an application which allows the user to create their own form.

By that I mean that the app would provide a way of designing how the data looks: the fields (names/properties) and their types. By "type" I mean that for each field specified, it can be chosen if it will be a text box, a check-box, a drop-down, etc.

It doesn't matter if it's a web or desktop app, but spreadsheet-like solutions are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Forms](http://forms.google.com) has the features you are looking for:

- It allows users to create their own forms
- They can choose the names/properties of each field
- They can select a type like: text, drop-down list, checkbox, multiple choice, etc...

[image]